# Group JSON object by key - jQuery .each()

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

```
{
    "employees": {
        "year 2010": [
            {
                "fn": "john",
                "ln": "doe",
            }, {
                "fn": "jane",
                "ln": "doe",
            }
        ],
        "year 2012": [
            {
                "fn": "jack",
                "ln": "frost",
            }, {
                "fn": "julie",
                "ln": "frost",
            }
        ],
        "year 2014": [
            {
                "fn": "frank",
                "ln": "green",
            }, {
                "fn": "steven",
                "ln": "green",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I loop through this JSON with the jQuery each() function and output it to the page in this structure. JSON can be formatted differently if need be, I just need to be able to output like listed below.

**Year 2010**

- John Doe
- Jane Doe

**Year 2012**

- Jack Frost
- Julie Frost

**Year 2014**

- Frank Green
- Steven Green

Answer (score 1):

Complete code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zsxe02f/5/).

```
var employees = json['employees'];

$.each(employees, function (key, data) {
    console.log(key);
    var cont = $(".container");
    cont.append("<h3>" + key + "</h3>");

    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
        console.log(data);
        cont.append("<p>" + data.fn + " " + data.ln + "</p>");
    })
})
```

It has very simple markup, but you can style it as you want.

Comment: how can i do it if the json is in an external file. Can I use getJSON() method? Also do I have to add var=json for this to work? @Kairat

Comment: @Angel, What do you mean by external? Is the json local but in a different file or is it hosted somewhere else?

Comment: the JSON file will end up being hosted on a CDN. so I would like my jQuery in a different file then the JSON @Kairat

Comment: @Angel, yeah in that case you can use `getJSON()` like so: `$.getJSON( "url.json", function( data ) {
 console.log(data);
})`. The `data` will be your json response.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var emps = {
    "employees": {
        "year 2010": [
            {
                "fn": "john",
                "ln": "doe",
            }, {
                "fn": "jane",
                "ln": "doe",
            }
        ],
        "year 2012": [
            {
                "fn": "jack",
                "ln": "frost",
            }, {
                "fn": "julie",
                "ln": "frost",
            }
        ],
        "year 2014": [
            {
                "fn": "frank",
                "ln": "green",
            }, {
                "fn": "steven",
                "ln": "green",
            }
        ]
    }
};

var arr = [];

$.each(emps.employees, function(i, v){
   $("#employees").append('<ul>'+i+'</lu>');
   $.each(v, function(j, e){
     $("#employees").last().append('<li>'+e.fn+' '+ e.ln+'</li>');
   });
   
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  }

li {
  padding-left: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="employees"></ul>
```